# What is my total grade average?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Task 1: $\dfrac{19}{30}$ worth $20\%$ of final grade

Task 2: $\dfrac{68}{80}$ worth $15\%$ of final grade

Task 3: $\dfrac{19}{46}$ worth $15\%$ of final grade

Task 4: $85\%$ , worth $15\%$ of final grade

Comment: The sum doesn't add up to 100%, is that normal ?

Comment: Yeah, so far not everything has been finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total of percentages : $20+15+15+15=65\%$

Grades, on $100$ points :

$\frac{19}{30}=\frac{63.33}{100},\frac{68}{80}=\frac{85}{100},\frac{19}{46}=\frac{41.30}{100}$ and last one is $\frac{85}{100}$

Therefore the average is $a=\dfrac{63.33*20+85*15+41.3*15+85*15}{65}=\frac{68}{100}$

Your average so far should be **68.25/100**

If you get $80\%$ on your last exam worth $35\%$ of the grade your final average will be :

$a=\dfrac{63.33*20+85*15+41.3*15+85*15+80*35}{100}=\frac{72}{100}$

Your final average would be **72.36/100**

Comment: Thanks, say the last exam I did I got 80%, which was worth 35% of my grade. What would my average then be?

Comment: @MahatmaGhandi Here, i edited it. Is that good ?

Answer (score 0):

The average of all of the scores, after converting each into percentages, is roughly **68%**.

I think what is probably better to know is the amount of total grade that you have attained so far. That is
$\frac{1}{5}.\frac{19}{30} + \frac{3}{20}\frac{68}{8o} + \frac{3}{20}\frac{19}{40} + \frac{3}{20}\frac{17}{20} \approx \frac{45}{100}$.

This means that to get whatever grade you are aiming for you need to consider
$$ \frac{35}{100}.\frac{x}{100}+\frac{45}{100} $$ and make sure that you score $x$ to get the final grade you want.

[EDIT]: this the other answer was changed after its initial post and now contains basically the same